# String method, select from email only username

Tags: javascript, string

it is possible to grab from email only data until @gmail.com ?

for example:

```
myemail@gmail.com
```

I want to select only

```
myemail
```

It should be aplycable for any emails. Any length of emails.

if I have emails:

```
myemail11@gmail.com and myem@gmail.com
```

it should give me:

```
myemail11 and myem
```

I thing req expreson will be good for that , but I am not goog in reg expr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is by getting string before last `@` by using `substring`:

```js
const address = "myemail@gmail.com";
const username = address.substring(0, address.lastIndexOf("@"));

console.log(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the substring, you can also split the email and take the first index value.

```
const email = "myemail@gmail.com";
const name = email.split('@')[0]

console.log(name)
```